# What vehicle is closer?

Tags: story

Detective Larry and Detective Torito have to meet up to exchange info about a murder case. Larry leaves the crime scene on a motorcycle that goes 80 mph heading east. Torito leaves the police station with his car than 60 mph heading west. The distance between each point is 72 miles.

**When they cross paths, who will be closer to the police station?**

Answer (score 6):

> If they meet, they're obviously just as far away...

Comment: Im sorry. I didnt realize you had posted your answer. +1 for you btw